# Copy text to clipboard and paste to HTML input like CTRL+V using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I write HTML code like this:

```
<div id='myText'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div><br>

<button id='myButton'>Paste</button><br>

<input id='pastedText' type='text' value='' name='pastedText' /><br>
```

How do I get when click "Paste" button, text in  copied into the clipboard and automatically pasted on . Maybe like when the user presses **CTRL + V** keys on the keyboard.

I do not want to use the operation append, prepend or set of values in javascript. I just want to paste the text in the input such as **CTRL + V**. Please share your references. *Thanks*.

Comment: this plugin would help https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: how to trig paste operation with clipboard.js?. I have to automatic copy to clipboard and paste to <input>. Not just copy text to clipbaord. thanks

Comment: The [Clipboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) may be of help, but check [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboard%20api) before using it to see if it fits your scenario.

Comment: my script just running in chrome, cause I'm write my script for chrome extension. I'll be try with https://github.com/layerssss/paste.js now.